# How can I use the results of data produced by the ".each" method?

Tags: scope, dexie

I use [Dexie.js](http://dexie.org/) (an `IndexedDb` wapper).

I've tried generating HTML like this:

```
function getList(where){
    var html = [];
    if($.isEmptyObject(where)) return;
    db.modules.where(where).each(function(item){
        html.push('<div class="module-item">');
        html.push('<div class="module-item-pic"><img src="' + item.modu_pic + '" class="img-fluid" /></div>');
        ....
        html.push('</div>')
        html.push('</div>');
    })
    console.log(html.join(''));
}
```

but the code above outputs nothing.

However, I get an output when I put `console.log(html.join(''))` inside the callback to `.each`:

```
function getList(where){
    var html = [];
    if($.isEmptyObject(where)) return;
    db.modules.where(where).each(function(item){
        html.push('<div class="module-item">');
        html.push('<div class="module-item-pic"><img src="' + item.modu_pic + '" class="img-fluid" /></div>');
        ....
        html.push('</div>')
        html.push('</div>');
console.log(html.join(''));
    })

}
```

Why is my first code snippet failing to show any output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that Dexie operations are generally asynchronous. The problem is that your first code snippet executes `console.log(html.join(''))` *immediately*, before any of the asynchronous operations are done.

You need to use the promise returned by [`.each`](http://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.each()) to wait until all iterations are complete before trying to output to the console:

```
function getList(where){
    var html = [];
    if($.isEmptyObject(where)) return;
    db.modules.where(where).each(function(item){
        html.push('<div class="module-item">');
        html.push('<div class="module-item-pic"><img src="' + item.modu_pic + '" class="img-fluid" /></div>');
        ....
        html.push('</div>')
        html.push('</div>');
    }).then(function () {
      console.log(html.join(''));
    });
}
```